# Extjs: Overwrite objects in a record ready to save

Tags: object, extjs, edit, record

Hi guys can anyone shed some light on how to do this please.

I have a userRecord object with various sub-objects in including things like their skills-sets, contracts etc.

I get the record by querying the store for the userId as below.

> var userRecord = userStore.findRecord('id', userId);

Next I have a variety of forms with checkboxes in a tabpanel relating to each of the user's sub-objects e.g. Skillsets and Contracts. I am trying to overwrite these on the userRecord with an array on checkboxes that have been checked.

> ```
>  var skillsetCheckBoxes = skillsetPanel.query('checkboxfield[checked=true]');
>  var skillsets = new Array();
>  Ext.each(skillsetCheckBoxes, function (skillset)
>  {
>      console.log(skillset);
>      skillsets.push(skillset);
>  });
> ```

I have tried to set the userRecord's engineer's skillset object to be the new array:

> ```
>    userRecord.set(('engineer').skillsets, skillsets);
> ```

But when I log the record after doing this it is still the same record I retrieved from findRecord() with no edited fields.

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing your model's structure, but your line is clearly wrong. You are using `('engineer').skillsets` as the key argument for the `set` method. Since it's not a string but an array, it won't do anything good.

Your line should rather be something like that:

```
// You should probably test that there is something in there, or the
// next line could crash...
var engineer = userRecord.get('engineer');
if (engineer) {
    userRecord.get('engineer').skillsets = skillsets;
}
```